# Comic book about a city of superheroes

Tags: story-identification, comics, super-hero

Here's all I remember from the comic: The comic was about a city filled with people with superpowers, the plot focused a lot on a group of teenage superheroes, who where mainly goth, the whole city had something to do with the fountain of youth, there was a guy who had a skull for a head and a snake, I remember I loved it but i don't remember the name and I want to re-read it.

Comment: So not http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalman then?

Comment: Or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powers_%28comics%29?

Comment: or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astro_City

Comment: Or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_10_(comics)

Comment: I'm thinking of the "Bicycle Repair-Man" sketch from Monty Python's Flying Circus.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like "Welcome to Tranquility" by Gail Simone (published by Wildstorm):
https://www.goodreads.com/series/72447-welcome-to-tranquility
https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/ComicBook/WelcomeToTranquility

The whole town was populated by "maxis" (retired superheroes/villains) and their offspring. In particular, there was a group of teenagers called the "Liberty Snots" (goths) and Henry Hyde (aka Henry Hate) had a skull for a head.

The overall plot is a murder mystery. Spoilers:

> Some of the "heroes" have been guarding the fountain of youth to stop getting old, but there isn't enough water for everyone so they've been killing to protect the secret.